# Swift: Search for a specific value in Firebase Database & find all associated data

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]
[image]

I have data uploading to my Database. I'm trying to implement Search functionality that I can search for something by the name, and if the name is found then autopopulate textfields with the data corresponding to that name. So for example if I search 'Pepsi Max' I want to find pepsi max in my database and then display the price/location/rating etc.

I currently have a Search function but that just searches the entire db and prints all values.

```
func searchT() {

    let pub = pubName.text

    print(pub)


    let databaseRef = Database.database().reference().child("Drinks")
    let query = databaseRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "pub").queryStarting(atValue: pub).queryEnding(atValue: "\(String(describing: pub))\\uf8ff")

    query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        guard snapshot.exists() != false else { return }
        print(snapshot.value as Any)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            guard let dict = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] else {
                print(snapshot)
                return
            }

            let pubName = dict["pub"] as? String
            let pubLocation = dict["location"] as? String
            let price = dict["price"] as? String
            let rating = dict["rating"] as? String
            let comment = dict["comment"] as? String

            self.pubName.text?.append(pubName!)
            self.pubLocation.text?.append(pubLocation!)
            self.price.text?.append(price!)
            self.rating.text?.append(rating!)
            self.comment.text?.append(comment!)

        }
    }
}
```

You will notice that in this function I'm searching by the data 'pubName' (which I think I'm setting incorrectly in the first line, but not sure how to correct it). This function crashes on the first line of setting the textViews to a value as there's 'nil while unwrapping an Optional value'

How can I search by pubName , locate the corresponding value and then set the textfields as the remaining data in the db relating to the searched value.

Thanks in advance, E

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. Realtime Database**

Since you haven't included the structure of your database, I assume you have a database structure for drinks like below:

[Screenshot of my Realtime database for this answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPCmc.png)

```
{
  "Drinks" : {
    "-LYiUHm4vtrB3LqCBxEc" : {
      "location" : "toronto",
      "name" : "pepsi max",
      "price" : 13.5,
      "rating" : 3.6
    },
    "-LYiUHm5Lgt3-LENTdBZ" : {
      "location" : "new york",
      "name" : "diet coke",
      "price" : 15.45,
      "rating" : 5
    },
    "-LYiUHm5Lgt3-LENTdB_" : {
      "location" : "chicago",
      "name" : "mountain dew",
      "price" : 2,
      "rating" : 2
    },
    "-LYiUHm5Lgt3-LENTdBa" : {
      "location" : "vancouver",
      "name" : "sprite",
      "price" : 6.98,
      "rating" : 4.5
    }
  }
}
```

**2. Swift 4.0**

Now, to search any drink by name use below code:

```
func search(drinkName: String) {
        let databaseRef = Database.database().reference().child("Drinks")
        let query = databaseRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "name").queryStarting(atValue: drinkName).queryEnding(atValue: "\(drinkName)\\uf8ff")

        query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
            guard snapshot.exists() != false else { return }
            //print(snapshot.value)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                // Update TextFields here
            }
        }
}
```

> The \uf8ff character used in the query above is a very high code point in the Unicode range. Because it is after most regular characters in Unicode, the query matches all values that start with a b.

Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data

> **Note:** queryOrderedByChild() is case-sensitive. It is nice practice to save all fields lowercased in database as this makes it easier to query data. You can always format strings in front end.

**3. Add ".indexOn" to Realtime Database's Rules**

In order to above query to work and achieve better performance, you need to set the index on the field that you are going to search by. 
You can do this by going to Rules tab and adding index like below:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
      "Drinks": {
        ".indexOn": "name"
      }
  }
}
```

Source: [More information on indexing data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data)

**Updated Answer for your updated question:**

```
func searchT() {
        // You must cast pub variable as String.
        guard let pub: String = pubName.text else { return }

        print(pub)


        let databaseRef = Database.database().reference().child("Drinks")

        let query = databaseRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "pub").queryStarting(atValue: pub).queryEnding(atValue: "\(String(describing: pub))\\uf8ff")

        query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
            guard snapshot.exists() != false else {
                print("failing here")
                return }
            print(snapshot.value as Any)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                guard let dict = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] else {
                    print(snapshot)
                    return
                }

                let pubName = dict["pub"] as? String
                let pubLocation = dict["location"] as? String
                let price = dict["price"] as? String
                let rating = dict["rating"] as? String
                let comment = dict["comment"] as? String
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your response! I have updated my code above to show my current progress. 

The code you pasted still prints all values in the database, not the specific value I'm looking for. Thank you!

Comment: @EoghanCasey Would you mind attaching screenshots of your Realtime database and Database Rules to your question? It will help me help you better.

Comment: Change these two lines in your code: guard let pub: String = pubName.text else { return } & let query = databaseRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "pub").queryStarting(atValue: pub).queryEnding(atValue: "\(pub)\\uf8ff")

Comment: Your query must be failing due pub variable as it is optional String. Making changes as above should fix it. Also, make sure you are querying pub name exactly as it is on database since this query is case-sensitive. Please let me know it helps.

Comment: the function isn't progressing past the line "guard snapshot.exists() != false else { return }" so nothing after that is taking place, no printing or anything. 

I've debugged it & can see the pub variable is working fine and as expected so there  is either something wrong with the query or snapshot

Thanks, E

Comment: Please try unwrapping optional variable pub and casting it to String using guard condition. I tried your code and it only works if I unwrap pub variable. Without unwrapping Swift converts automatically to Any. Please try this: guard let pub: String = pubName.text else { return }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188494/discussion-between-bhaumik-and-eoghan-casey).